# Using JavaScript console modifies outcome of script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In Chrome, this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ujmy/1/) prints `false`. However, the same code typed in the JavaScript console prints `true`:

```
a = 1;
var a = 2;
console.log(delete a);​
```

Why do I get different results depending on whether or not I'm using the Chrome console?

Comment: any particular reason for doing this? :)

Comment: Pasting this into console gives `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`, Chrome (Linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the Chrome console runs inside an `eval` construct or something similar, rather than running in the global scope.

There is a *lot* of discussion about the `delete` operator here on StackOverflow.  A search for `[javascript] delete` will help answer other questions that come up.

Answer (score 0):

`var` defined variables can not be deleted.

Comment: Apparently you can in the Chrome console, though, which is the OPs question.  I tried it myself; he's right.